# Creating lookup site column with site scripts

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, site-design, site-script

I am trying to create some look-up columns in my site (not in the list) with site scripts. I have succesfully been able to create one:

```
{
  "verb": "createSiteColumnXml",
  "schemaXml": "<Field Type=\"Lookup\" ID=\"{41a37806-6c69-4ec0-bb83-fdaa69eed277}\" DisplayName=\"Lookup Column\" Required=\"TRUE\" Name=\"IN_LookupColumn\" StaticName=\"IN_LookupColumn\" Group=\"Test group\" List=\"{9901cb58-72e5-4173-aeec-ca47506b1245}\" ShowField=\"IN_ColumnaDeProva\" AllowDeletion=\"TRUE\" />"
}
```

The problem here is that I require having previously the list ID to be able to create it succesfully. I want to create the list itself with site script and then create a site lookup column pointing to that list, so I won't really have the list ID to "hard code" it to the schemaXml. I've tried with the list display name but without success.

Does anyone have any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever found a solution?